# Plotting the effect of more predictors over a dependent variable in GLMs

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, ggplot2

I want to plot the effect of the predictors considered (V1, V2....Vn) over a dependent variable based on the following results obtained from the summary of GLM (negative binomial distribution):

```
summary(step.model)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = HCC_2 ~ WF + MS + GM + CGCA + AA + UA + RED + 
    BOAR + ROE, data = d2.df, init.theta = 2.752752025, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.47692  -0.78850  -0.26249   0.09616   2.92812  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -29.7630    12.0866  -2.462  0.01380 * 
V1            0.2679     0.1196   2.240  0.02512 * 
V2            0.3678     0.1351   2.723  0.00647 **
V3            0.3038     0.1111   2.734  0.00626 **
V4            0.3758     0.1441   2.607  0.00914 **
V5            0.6152     0.2337   2.633  0.00846 **
V6            0.1977     0.1070   1.847  0.06474 . 
V7           -0.4255     0.1651  -2.578  0.00995 **
V8           -2.1156     0.7859  -2.692  0.00710 **
V9            0.5937     0.2539   2.339  0.01936 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(2.7528) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 48.547  on 36  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 32.231  on 27  degrees of freedom
AIC: 204.35

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  2.753 
          Std. Err.:  0.887 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -182.347
```

As you can see, almost all the predictors have a significant effect over the dependent variable. How can I plot these effects in a single chart? I look at the ggplot function, but I didn't find exaustive explanations. Please, can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the *effects* package? Not sure it works with glm.nb, but if if does, try something like *plot(allEffects(step.model))*.  Is step.model produced by stepwise regression? Then the reported p-values don't account for the uncertainty involved in the variable selection process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't look at the effect package but surely I will. As far as concerns the second question, yes these are results obtained from a stepwise regression analysis. However, I didn't understand what do you mean when you say that "the reported p-values don't account for the uncertainty involved in the variable selection process". Many thanks again.

Comment: Stepwise regression has a bad reputation in the statistical community - it essentially produces p-values which cannot be trusted. This forum has tons of posts on stepwise regression and its perils.  Just do a search to see what I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.